# how do I add a submodule to my repos

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, octopress

I cloned octopress from github.

When I try to add directories in there, I get the following error:

```
git add source/*
fatal: Pathspec 'source/about' is in submodule 'octopress'
```

Comment: In which folder are your when you do the `git add source/*` ?

Answer (score 0):

You add the `source/*` directly. you have to go into the folder and then add and commit your content it it.

Submodules are standlone folders (repositories)and you have to add and commit files within the directory itself.

```
cd source

# add the content 
git add .

# Commit the changes
git commit -m "Added Octopress source"

# push updates
git push origin <branch name>
```

Since you have modified the source directory of Octopress you also need to generate the content to be sure that you have the latest generated files.

```
# generate the content
rake generate

# Deploy the changes in case you need to deploy them.
```